# 位置情報が有効になっているかを調べたい

Tags: android, java

Androidで位置情報を利用するアプリを作っているのですが、端末の位置情報を利用する設定がオフになっている場合にダイアログを出す処理を作りたいです。
端末の位置情報が有効になっているかどうかをJavaのプログラムで取得するにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

Comment: リンク先のコード参考にすれば出来ると思いますよ
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

必要なパーミッション(`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` や `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`)があるなら、`LocationManager#isProviderEnabled(providerName)` で確認できます。

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled(java.lang.String)

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
final boolean gpsEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
final boolean wifiEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

あるいは、https://stackoverflow.com/a/22219239 のように `LOCATION_MODE` を見る方法もあるようです。